# How Control flow for multiple recursive function work

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have always found it hard to understand when their are multiple recursive function inside a function body.
Lets take an example of merge sort.

```
array = [2,4,5,6,7]
function mergeSort(array, left, right){ 
  if(left < right){
    mid = left + (right - left)/2;
    mergeSort(array, left, mid);
    mergeSort(array, mid+1, right);
    // rest of code
    ...
 }
```

Firstly I know how function call stack works .
 Here the first merge sort will call itself in this way.

The function call stack for first merge sort.

- mergeSort(array, 0,1);
- mergeSort(array, 0,2)

  I cannot understand how will the second merge sort work.
  Though when I log the results it returns the following.
- mergeSort(array, 3,4)
- mergeSort(array, 3,5);

I am doing it in Javascript
So if we take a single threaded environment like javascript has how will it keep track of multiple values like in this case.
As 
mergeSort(array,0,2) is called the control should flow again to the same function and the value of left and right should be lost for the second reccursive merge function below it, but somehow the second recurssive function gets the value left =3 and right = 5. So does the two function run parrallely.

In short how does the runtime keeps track of multiple values of left and right.

Comment: It will wait till the current one finishes.

Comment: ...are you sure you know how a call stack works..

Comment: So when the current execution stops does it mean that the function will have the following codes in its body left = 0 and right = 5 and mid =2.Which  was the first function added in the stack?

Comment: You should have a look at this article about the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Your question is very interesting, and the call stack is actually the mechanism that allows the program not to get lost in its recursive calls.